# Is it possible to access the HibernateEntityManagerFactory in a custom BeanPostProcessor?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

In a Spring Boot application I'm trying to get hold on the `HibernateEntityManagerFactory` from a custom `BeanPostProcessor` like:

```
public class HibernateEventListenerBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private HibernateEntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        // TODO do the stuff with beans of various types
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.entityManagerFactory = applicationContext.getBean(HibernateEntityManagerFactory.class);
    }
}
```

But it gives me:

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManagerFactory] is defined
```

When I try to autowire the `HibernteEntityManagerFactory` in normal bean this works without problems. E.g.:

```
@Component
public class HibernateEventListenerRegistrar {

    private HibernateEntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateEventListenerRegistrar(HibernateEntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, List<HibernateEventListener> hibernateEventListeners) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerListeners() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get access to the `HibernateEntityManagerFactory` in a Spring `BeanPostProcessor`?

Comment: if [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/70899-unable-to-inject-entitymanagerfactory-nullpointerexception) is of any help.

Comment: Thanks for link but I don't how it can help... let me know if you think otherwise

Comment: Why not just turn HibernateEventListenerRegistrar into a @Configuration class instead of a @Component? No need to deal with bean post processors

Comment: @geoand How should that work? I need to do some stuff with beans of various types. That's why I was thinking of a BeanPostProcessor. Als important that they be Ordered aware.

Comment: Looking at your code, I thought that what you need to do is summorized by `HibernateEventListenerRegistrar`. Since it is meant to be part of the Spring configuration you should use `@Configuration` instead of `@Component`

Comment: @geoand I see. I've updated the original question with a TODO in the postProcessAfterInitialization

Comment: @MarcelOverdijk I added my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allow you to register your Hibernate listeners:

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateExtraConfig {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateEntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl) hibernateEntityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactoryImpl.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
    }
}

@Component
public class HibernateListenersConfigurer {

    private final EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry;
    private final YourListener yourListener;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateListenersConfigurer(EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry,
                                        YourListener yourListener) {

        this.eventListenerRegistry = eventListenerRegistry;
        this.yourListener= yourListener;

        configureListeners();
    }

    private void configureListeners() {
        eventListenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_INSERT).appendListener(yourListenerctListener);
        eventListenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_UPDATE).appendListener(yourListenerctListener);

        //whatever other events you need
    }
}
```

With the code above the listener would look like:

```
public class YourListener implements PostInsertEventListener, PostUpdateEventListener {

   @Override
   public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {

   }

   //you might also need this depending on your transaction configuration and what you are trying to do in  the listeners
   @Override
   public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister persister) {
      return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Problem is that I have multiple listeners and I don't want them to autowire this way. I'm looking for a more dynamic approach (so it might be suitable for other project as well). That's why I would like to register any bean that implements PostInsertEventListener, PostUpdateEventListener, etc. Based on the interface I would like to register to the appropriate event listener group. That's why I was thinking the BeanPostProcessor would be my best option.

Comment: You can probably adapt the code in this answer to be more dynamic and not rely on autowiring of the listeners. It's better than your approach because it doesn't force early instantiation of the `EntityManagerFactory` (`BeanPostProcessors` are special and you should try and avoid doing anything to the bean factory in their initializers).

Comment: One solution would be to autowire something like `List<PostInsertEventListener>` (as well as the other relevant listeners) and work with those